# I would like to update my app UI, but ONLY if my app is in the foreground

Tags: android, user-interface, foreground

I have an app that is very simple - it turns bluetooth on and off according to whether it's plugged in.

The app right now is also very simple in terms of UI - there is 1 button on there, that allows you to turn bluetooth on and off if you want.

I actually have this working, and have figured out how to update the button, but, I would like to update my UI only if the app is in the foreground - so, if I plug in my phone, and i'm NOT in my app, I *don't* want my app to pop up and update the UI - I only want the UI to change if the app was open when I plugged in the phone.

I've tried the following code, and it does find the app in the running apps list, but it opens the app no matter what - i.e., it'll open the app and update my UI whether it was open before or not.

```
  ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
  List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    for(RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses){
        if(appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
            Log.i("Foreground App", appProcess.processName);
            if(appProcess.processName.equals("vermel.BluetoothOn")) {
                    //update UI
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Please bear in mind, I'm a fresh newbie in both Java and Android, and would highly appreciate details explanation, as opposed to a link to the android development documentation ;)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

if you add `@Override onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` to your Activity you'll be able to track when you have focus and when you don't. you can then wait until you have focus to update your UI.

Comment: hmm, but, if i'm INSIDE the window already, the focus of the window isn't going to change - will this still work?

Comment: When you're in the background, won't you lose focus?

Comment: well, i don't want to gain focus. the app only turns bt on/off - i don't want to even have an interface for it. however, if it does happen to be open, i need to update the interface. I've written things a bit since i posted that code above, and it seems like what i need is to try running that "running processes" inside my receiver, to determine if i'm in foreground - if i put it in my main activity, i'll just bring that to the foreground, which is not what i want.but i'm willing to bet that code won't work inside BradcastReceiver, and i'm not sure what to do.

Comment: ok, when I answered your question, you were proposing to have a UI that could gain or lose focus.

Comment: sorry, this is the main thing I'm looking for: "I only want the UI to change if the app was open when i plug in the phone." I've since re-written changing the BT state when plugged in as a service that does what i want, but I still have the same issue - I can't tell if my app is running or not. IF and ONLY IF the app is running in the foreground (i.e. the user is looking at it right now), I want to update the UI. if it's not running in the foreground, I want to do nothing. is that more clear? sorry about the confusion..